Linker command failed with exit code 1 & Command Phase execution error
I am currently working on RN project. My React native version is 0.66.5. And i am using Apple Mac Pro with M3 Chip . I ma trying to run my code in Xcode (xcode version 15). And i am getting error based on some architecture. I tried many solution but nothing worked for me. Please anyone help me.
Initially i got around 32 errors.
Showing All Errors Only
Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS$_GPBRootObject
Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS$_GTMLogMininumLevelFilter
Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS$_GTMLogger
Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS$_GTMSessionCookieStorage
Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS$_GTMSessionFetcher
Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS$_GTMSessionFetcherService
Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS$_GULCCComponent
Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS$_GULCCComponentContainer
Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS$_GULCCComponentType
Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS$_GULUserDefaults
Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS$_RCTBridge
Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS$_RCTBundleURLProvider
Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS$_RCTLinkingManager
Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS$_RCTRootView
Undefined symbol: OBJC_METACLASS$_GPBMessage
Undefined symbol: OBJC_METACLASS$_GPBRootObject
Undefined symbol: OBJC_METACLASS$_GTMLogger
Undefined symbol: _kGTMSessionFetcherStatusDomain
Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
So i  tried some solutions and added arm64 and x86_64 in excluded architecture. After that getting error like
Showing All Errors Only
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
Tried with any one of the excluded architecture then too getting the errors.
Please guide me on this . Thanks in advance.
I tried adding excluded architectures like arm64, x86_64 both and each separately. When i add x86_64 in excluded architecture getting Command phase execution error. when i remove getting Linker command failed issue.

I solved this just by adding x86_64 in excluded arch
